# How to create a newContext in playwright for api request

Tags: api, cucumber, playwright, fixtures

Cucumber and API test
I am trying to integrate my api test with cucumber and getting the
Error: function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces: callback and promise

Feature file

```
    Scenario: Get Authentication token
    Given I send a request for authentication token
    Then I get an access token
```

Step.js file

```
const {Given, When, Then} = require('@cucumber/cucumber')
```

var token
Given('I send a request for authentication token', async ({request})=> {

```
  let top = "2"
  let name = "Nike"
  let baseUrl =  `https://apistaging.swordfish-new-co-ecs-nonprod.com/ned/employers?$top=${top}&name=${name}`
                  
  const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Api-Version': '2',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  }
  const response = await request.get(baseUrl,{headers: headers,})
  const responsebody = await(await response.json())
  await expect(responsebody).toHaveLength(2)
  console.log(responsebody)
})
```

Possible solution may be create a new context page that would allow to use request fixture.

```
Before(async () => { console.log('Create new context and page') global.context = await global.browser.newContext()   global.page = await global.context.newPage()})
```

Error

```
Error: function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces: callback and promise
   to use the callback interface: do not return a promise
   to use the promise interface: remove the last argument to the function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
const apiContext = await request.newContext({
    extraHTTPHeaders: headers
});
const response = await apiContext.get(baseUrl);
const responsebody = await response.json()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).